# i want to display accordion under selected Book appointment Button in ng-repeat, here it is displaying in first button

Tags: angularjs, html

i want to display accordion under selected Book appointment Button in ng-repeat,But here it is displaying under first button..Please help! I Attached screen shot also..[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8PzC.png)

```
<tbody ng-repeat="schedule in scheduleListByDate | orderBy:'scheduledDate':false">
   <tr>
       <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
       <td>{{changeDateformate(schedule.scheduledDate);}}</td>        
       <td>{{schedule.doctor.firstName}}{{schedule.doctor.lastName}}</td>
       <td>{{schedule.fromTime | date:'HH:mm:ss'}}</td>
       <td>{{schedule.toTime | date:'HH:mm:ss'}}</td>
       <td>{{arrayToString(schedule.availableDays)}}</td>
       <td>
          <button class="btn label-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo" ng-click="findScheduledHours(schedule);">Book
        Appointment</button>
        <div id="demo" class="collapse">
            <form class="col-sm-12">        
               <div ng-repeat="scheduledHour in hoursList">
                  <div class="col-sm-3">
                     <button type="button" class="buttonAppointment" ng-click="selectScheduleSub(scheduledHourDto,scheduledHourDto.appointmentStartedDate,appointment.appointmentEnddate,scheduledHour);">{{scheduledHour}}</button>
                  </div>
               </div> 
            </form>
         </div>
      </td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try giving each one a unique `id` and corresponding `data-target`:

```
<button class="btn label-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo_{{$index}}" ng-click="findScheduledHours(schedule);">Book Appointment</button>
<div id="demo_{{$index}}" class="collapse">
    <form class="col-sm-12">        
        <div ng-repeat="scheduledHour in hoursList">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <button type="button" class="buttonAppointment" ng-click="selectScheduleSub(scheduledHourDto,scheduledHourDto.appointmentStartedDate,appointment.appointmentEnddate,scheduledHour);">{{scheduledHour}}</button>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </form>
</div>
```